# Flutter erro Post - DataTime

Tags: rest, flutter, dart

Está ocorrendo a seguinte situação no meu projeto. Eu tenho um model que tem uma propriedade do tipo DateTime, no Tojson eu passo a data para o json usando o toIso8601String, no caso eu apenas coloco a data atual ao pressionar o botao

```
onPressed: () {                                
                                    controllerPV.pedidoVenda.dATA = new DateTime.now();
                                    controllerPV.pedidoVenda.cANCELADO = 'N';
                                    controllerPV.pedidoVenda.mSGADICIONAL = controllerMsgEdicional.text;
                                    controller.submit();                 
                                  }
```

E depois no repositories eu monto o body e dou um post

```
Parametros parametros = Parametros();
    await parametros.buscarParametros();

    var body = json.encode(
        pvenda.toJson(),
    );

    http.Response response = await http.post(
      parametros.url_api + URL_PVendasInserir,
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      },
      body: body
    );
```

a data convertida, fica desta maneira[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas ao dar o post retorna o status 500 e a mensagem "Cannot read JSON property of type = "TDateTime", invalid value.". então peguei o body e fiz um teste no postman, e percebi que trocando a data 2021-03-06T10:42:38.774478 para 2021-03-06T10:42:38 funcionava, assim presumo que o erro seja referente a essa parte do milissegundos (.774478). Teria alguma forma de retira-los na hora de converter, ou devo fazer outra coisa ?

Comment: Se o erro é STATUS 500 após o post, provavelmente o problema é na sua API... Você precisa arrumar dentro da sua API para que ela entenda o tipo TIMESTAMP ou fazer um cast para transformar em data antes de enviar pelo post

Comment: Entendi, e como eu poderia converter DateTime para TimeStamp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

não percebo bem o seu código
mas assim resumindo vai precisar apenas de [int](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)package para formatar

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

main() {
  var now = new DateTime.now();
  var formatter = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
  String formatted = formatter.format(now);
  print(formatted); // something like 2013-04-20
}
```

documentação[clique me](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

Qualquer duvida estou aqui mano